# Estimating reaching probabilities of a simple random walk

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm currently reading the paper ["Simple Random Walk"](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf) from Sven Erick Alm.

Nearly everything  is clear, except for the one inequality.

A simple random walk started at $0$, with probability $p$ of going up ($+1$) and $q=1-p$ of going down ($-1$). He defined $P_k(n)$ as the probability to reach $x=k$ in the first $n$ steps and claims that conditioning on the first step gives
$$
P_1(n) = p + qP_2(n-1) \le p+qP_1^2(n-1).
$$

I am having problem with the inequality on the RHS. Is there an easy explanation for it?

I tried to prove it rigorously using induction, but so far I didn't get satisfying results.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Seems like the only thing you need to prove is that $P_2(n-1) \le P_1^2(n-1)$, does that make sense?

Comment: Also confused somewhat by that definition of $P_k(n)$. If the position of random walk is $S_n$, does that mean $S_n = k$ or that the first hitting time of $k$ is at most $n$?

Comment: The definition is the probability, that the first hitting time of k is at most n.

Comment: The first mentioned inequality isn't obvious for me, since the RHS is the probability of hitting 1 in less than n steps and from 1 hitting 2 in less than n steps, which is, for me like only one of the ways of getting from 0 to 2.

Comment: I thought about that interpretation, that would imply that $P_2(n) \le P_1^2(n/2)$ though or something like that... more precisely, 
$$
P_2(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P_1(k) P_1(n-k)
$$

Comment: That makes sense, I'll think about it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Not really a hint - thinking together with you here :)

Comment: I think, it's not the way, because I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show $P_2(n-1) \le P_1(n-1)^2$, or in other words $P(\text{random walk hits $2$ in $n-1$ steps}) \le P(\text{random walk hits $1$ in $n-1$ steps})^2$.

Let $\tau$ be the first time the random walk $X$ hits $1$, and define $\hat X$ to be a random walk started at $1$ at time $\tau$ (basically thinking of restarting our random walk when it hits $1$ the first time).  The strong Markov property implies $X$ is independent of $\hat X$.  Then \begin{align*}P(\text{$X$ hits $2$ in $n-1$ steps}) &= P(\text{$X$ hits $1$ in $\tau$ steps and $\hat X$ hits $1$ in $n-1-\tau$ steps}) \\
&= P(\text{$X$ hits $1$ in $\tau$ steps}) P(\text{$\hat X$ hits $1$ in $n-1-\tau$ steps}) \\
&\le P(\text{$X$ hits $1$ in $n-1$ steps}) P(\text{$\hat X$ hits $1$ in $n-1$ steps}) \\
&= P(\text{$X$ hits $1$ in $n-1$ steps})^2 \\
&= P_1(n-1)^2.
\end{align*}

That's not a rigorous proof or anything, but that's the basic idea: to hit $2$ in $n-1$ steps, you have to independently hit $1$ twice in less than $n-1$ steps.  You can make this rigorous by being a little more careful about how you define $\hat X$.

Comment: The definition of X^ won't be that hard to do formally, I think. Can I assume, that tau is w. l. o. g. <= n-1, since if it would be bigger, the LHS would be equal to 0?

Comment: @user1047209 I think that handling the case where $\tau > n-1$ is where most of the difficulty in making this rigorous comes from.

Comment: But if $\tau = n-1$ then we already have, that the LHS equals 0, since one cannot get from 1 to 2 in 0 steps; if its value is even bigger this makes even less sense, to get from 1 to 2 in $<0$ steps.

Comment: @user1047209 The LHS is not random, so it can't equal $0$ depending on the value of the random variable $\tau$.  It's correct that $P(\text{$X$ hits 2 in $n-1$ steps}, \tau \ge n-1) = 0$, but I think the justification for appealing to the strong markov property might get murky once you add in the extra event $\{\tau < n-1\}$ (maybe not, I might be misremembering here).  Again, this all makes sense intuitively, and I think provides an explanation for the inequality, but rigorously justifying everything might be tricky.

Comment: Couldn't we actually just argue:
Let $\tau$ be the time from $0$ to $1$ and $\sigma$ the time from $1$ to $2$. Then $\tau \overset{d}{=} \sigma$, which follows from the Markov property.
$\sigma$ is independent of $\tau$, since the Markov chain doesn't remember, what was before. We then interpret the event on the LHS as $\{\tau + \sigma \leq n-1\}$, on the RHS, due to ind., as $\{ \tau \leq n-1 \} \cap \{ \sigma \leq n-1 \}$. The left event is a subset of  the right, due to $\sigma , \tau \geq 0$, if $\sigma + \tau \leq n-1$ then $\sigma, \tau \leq n-1$.
Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1047209 Yes, I think that works.